# writing $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ instead of $x$ in properties of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While doing properties of definite integral I found something. They wrote

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x\mathrm dx}{\sin x+\cos x}$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\mathrm dx}{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\cos (\frac{\pi}{2} -x)}$$

The problem arise in third line.
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\mathrm dx}{\sin x+\cos x}$$

My question is when removing $\frac{\pi}{2}$, Than I have to change for numerator also. But, why it only changed in denominator not in numerator?

Comment: They have, it's just that $\sin(90°-x)=\cos x$ and $\cos(90°-x)=\sin x$, so the sum remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because, for any real number $x$,$$\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\sin(x)\quad\text{and}\quad\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\cos(x).$$